# Retrieve all the available objects in Redis on page load nodejs / react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redis

i have a `nodejs/react` app and i know how to store data in objects in `redis` (hmset),

but the issue is i want to get all the hashes with its values stored in redis db, rather than getting one by one as below function,

1. is there any redis built in function to do this?
2. if not what are the options available for me to execute this functionality?

```
redisClient.hgetall(category, (err, object) => {
      if(err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        console.log(object);
      }
    });
```

Comment: There is not a redis built-in to handle this specific case, but there are several ways to solve this issue. In order to provide a reasonable solution, I have a couple questions: 
  • are there mixed data types in this redis, or is every key occupied by a hash? (is each key storing a category)
  • how many total category keys/values are you expecting to store?

Comment: my use case is i want to get all the data available in redis db and show it in a table, for an instance one row of data will look like this ```{ javascript: 'ReactJS', css: 'TailwindCSS', node: 'Express' }``` and my idea was to save key/value pairs under a hash and get all the hashes available and render the key/value under each hash, there could be 500 +/-  rows of data , so i was thinking each row data i store under a unique hash and get all the hashes and its related key/value pairs. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your response, I'll assume that there are more than just `category` entries in your redis. That being the assumption, here's a solution that is moderately common and that I've used before:

Use a separate SET to track the keys that contain category records. Since SETs deduplicate already, you don't need to worry about duplicate entries

```
redis.hset(categoryKey, ...things);
redis.sadd(categoryKeysTracker, categoryKey);
```

Somewhere else in your code, when you want to pull all of your categories if the number of records balloons, you should really use SSCAN to iterate through the entries of a SET instead of popping SMEMBERS on a very large entry.

Now I used async/await syntax here, because I didn't lookup the old async library signature for doing chunked callback-based async requests, but that should be pretty easy if you're still in a callback system. Keep in mind the number of promises you may be generating and probably chunk this request somehow.

```
const keys = await redis.smembers(categoryKeysTracker);
const categories = await Promise.all(keys.map((key) => {
  return redis.hgetall(key);
});
```

When/if you delete a category entry by calling DEL on a key, you'll also call SREM on the same key within the tracking set

```
redis.del(categoryKey);
redis.srem(categoryKeysTracker, categoryKey);
```

Something else to think about is doing the writing operations (set, delete) within a MULTI block, though that's not a hard requirement.

Comment: so this `return redis.hgetall(key);` returns all the keys but to get the values of all the keys i need to use again `hgetall` right?

Comment: ah nvm thats to return all the values for each `key`

Comment: thank you this looks like a good solution! let me try

Comment: I'm trying to return the values as below but its `undefined`
How can i return the hgetall value? 
```function createMobs(callback) {
  client.smembers("categoryKeysTracker", async function(err, reply) {
    console.log("reply::", reply);
    await Promise.all(
      reply.map((key) => {
        client.hgetall(key, function(err, obj) {
          console.log("reply::22", obj);
          callback(obj);
        });
      })
    );
  });
}
let keysArr = [];
const dd = createMobs(function(object) {
  console.log("95::", object);
  keysArr.push(object);
  return object;
});```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use [RediSearch](https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/), it was created to solve this very problem. You just need to [create an index](https://redis.io/commands/ft.create/) to make your Hashes searchable:

`FT.CREATE category:index ON HASH PREFIX 1 category: SCHEMA field TAG another_field NUMERIC a_third_field TEXT`

And then you can [search](https://redis.io/commands/ft.search/) it:

`FT.SEARCH category:index '@field:{ javascript | typescript } @another_field:[23 42] @a_third_field:patterns`

If you want *everything*—which is sounds like you do—you can search for that too:

`FT.SEARCH category:index '*'`

Comment: is it possible to see some nodejs implementations on above approach?